# Why does the need to explicitly choose a mean in `Arima()` depends on differencing or not the seasonal component of a ts?

Tags: r, time-series

Compare

```
Arima(ts(rnorm(100), freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1), 
                              fixed = c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
```

yielding

```
Series: ts(rnorm(100), freq = 4) 
ARIMA(1,0,1)(1,1,1)[4] 

Coefficients:
 ar1   ma1  sar1  sma1  
 0.5  -0.4   0.3  -0.2  

sigma^2 = 2.045:  log likelihood = -170.59
AIC=343.18   AICc=343.22   BIC=345.74
```

to

```
Arima(ts(rnorm(100), freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1), 
                              fixed = c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
```

returning an error:

```
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  wrong length for 'fixed'
```

The difference between both commands is simply differencing the seasonal component. I understand that `include.mean = T` is the default in `Arima()`, but provided there is differencing of the seasonal component, it doesn't seem to be necessary to include it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant defaults for `forecast::Arima()` are:

> - `include.mean = TRUE`
> - `include.drift = FALSE`

When an ARIMA model contains no differences (`d=0` and `D=0`), then the constant will act as the mean (and so is included by default since `include.mean = TRUE`).

When an ARIMA model contains a difference (`d=1` or `D=1`) then the constant will act as a drift term (and so is excluded by default since `include.drift = FALSE`).